# Unresolved reference in findViewById when using Glide in Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, fragment

I am new to Kotlin.  I have an "unresolved reference:findViewByid" when I am using Fragment.  I try to add "view?.findViewByid", but the app crashed and *val imgUniverse* returns "null".  Is there a way to solve it?.  Thanks.

I am trying to implement swipe pictures on different xml on multiple screens using PageViewer2.

KC

```
class Page1Fragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val imgUniverse = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_universe)  // Unresolved reference in findViewById
        val imgFooter = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_footer)    // Unresolved reference in findViewById

        Log.d("testing2: " , imgUniverse.toString())

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.universe3)
            .fitCenter()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imgUniverse!!)

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.footer)
            .fitCenter()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imgFooter!!)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false)


    }


}
```

Comment: post your code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for views before you are inflating (creating) them. The view is created in the last line with by inflating it using `inflater.inflate()`. Before that, none of the views even exists and therefore cannot be found and used.

Move all the code (except for the last line) into `onViewCreated()` and it will work.